# Instancing not working the way I want it to

Tags: rigging, vertices, customization, instances, transform-orientation

I am studying blender and I am at the instancing part and I am literally following the instructions on how to instance step by step and it is not working for me. These are the steps on the documentation [image]

I created a cube and scaled it and then I added an icosphere and then made the ico-sphere the parent of the cube [image]

And then I instanced it and this is what I got[![enter image description here][3]][3]

I don't understand what I am doing wrong i followed everything the way they did it on the docs what's the matter?

When I put the cube in the center same position as the icosphere I get this. FYI I want to create a ball with tentacles just like they did on the docs

[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPqgn.jpg[image]

Comment: it works as it is supposed to, the cubes are instanced around the original, and it follows the shape of the parent. It won't stick to the parent. If you want to you need to put the cube at the same position as the sphere.

Comment: @moonboots I have put the cube at the same position as the sphere but look what I got. I have posted the picture of what I got on the question. Why did it work for them though on the docs because their Screenshots show the cube and the icosphere side by side not same position

Answer (score 2):

You need to rotate the tentacle in Edit Mode so it aligns properly.

> Orientation of the tentacle was adapted to the vertex normals of the parent mesh
>    (tentacle was rotated -90° around the X axis in Edit Mode).
>
> *From Blender Manual*

*Step 01 - Set up Parenting*

[image]

*Step 02 - Rotate tentacle in Edit mode. I changed pivot point to 3D cursor for this.*

[image]